# Tech stack to learn for developing an Cooking AI assistant

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I am interested in creating a cooking website that utilizes AI technology. The website should allow users to input the name of a desired recipe and provide further prompts to filter and suggest recipe options. Additionally, the website should enable users to single-click shop for any missing ingredients or redirect to a service like Amazon for purchase.

I am seeking guidance on which technologies to learn for this project. If there are multiple options for a particular task, I prefer to learn the technology that is currently in demand in the market. For example, React has more future potential compared to other libraries, although it may not be the most commonly used library at present. If there is no clear market trend, I prefer to learn the technology that is most widely used, such as the Python way for machine learning.

For reference, I have experience with Python3, NumPy, Pandas, Matplotlib, Seaborn, data scraping using Selenium and BeautifulSoup, HTML, CSS (including animations), JS (DOM manipulation), and C.

Comment: What do you want to do with python? There are thousands of modules you could use. It all depends on what you want to learn to do.

Comment: I'd say visit [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/) and start by what grabs your attention - at least I did. But otherwise I'd say `pathlib`, `itertools`, `functools`, `asyncio`, `logging`, `argparse`, `datetime` would be a stable ground

Comment: I would suggest Numpy, Pandas, Scikit-Learn. And goodluck.

Comment: I am now well versed with Numpy, Pandas, Matplotlib, Seaborn and now on scikit-learn but unable to decide should I go with it or should I pick some other library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not enough rep for comment, but **MatplotLib** is a good one!

Comment: thankyou am I proper that it is used for visualizing my mathematical curves?